# Затранскрибируйте текст

Tags: транскрипция

Помогите пожалуйста, очень нужна помощь в транскрипции текста, и прокомментировать какие фонетические законы отображенны в транскрипции:
 С горы бежит поток проворный,
 В лесу не молкнет птичий гам,
 И гам лесной и шум нагорный-
 Всё вторит весело громам.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не пойдёт такое дело, Вы затранскрибируйте, а мы поправим. И напишите, какая транскрипция-фонетическая, фонематическая, какой уровень - школа,вуз, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

згΛры б'и(с призвуком е)жыт пΛток прΛворный/-( закон редукции гласных в слабой позиции, "зг"-закон ассимиляции по звонкости)

вл'и(е)су  н'и(е)молкн'ьт  пт'ич'ий гам/-закон редукции

игам  л'и(е)сной/ ишум нΛгорный//-закон редукции

фс'о фтор'ит в'ес'илъ грΛмам- (фс'о фтор'ит - ассимиляция по глухости)

Answer (score 1):

Представленный вариант транскрипции является фонетическим. И, похоже, здесь вузовский уровень. 
      Фонетические процессы в целом отражены и определены верно. Однако в слове 
``             н'и(е)молкн'Ит в заударной позиции вместо звука И следует указать Ь.
       Редукция охарактеризована поверхностно, т.к. не указаны её тип и степень.
       Вообще не указана аккомодация. 
       В транскрипции связного текста следует выделять фразы и речевые такты (синтагмы).
Понятно, что по техническим причинам, наверно, сложно   было указать ударение.

Comment: Автор нам так и не указал, какой уровень нужен. Если б это был вуз,вряд ли такой вопрос последовал бы, возможно, колледж. Там, вероятно, аккомодация не указывается.Мы не знаем, что нужно.